# focus event is getting called before writeValue() when using custom directive inside ag-Grid cell Editor

Tags: ag-grid, angular-directive, controlvalueaccessor

**Goal**: Make ag-Grid cell editable as a currency control.

**Approach**:

1. Created a custom directive for currency.
2. Created a custom cell editor, which uses that currency directive.

**Issue**:

In a normal scenario, on page load, control with directive (implements ControlValueAccesor) loads and writeValue() is called to initialize the value in the control. So, I'm displaying the value with the currency($) symbol using writeValue(). And when, user clicks on the control, I'm displaying the value without currency symbol by writing the logic in focus event.

Now, with ag-Grid, directive would not load on page load. It would load when control is clicked, since it is enclosed within a cell editor. So, on click/focus, the following gets called in the following order -

1. focus event - It would set the control value to null, since no value has been set yet using writeValue. But soon after that, writeValue() is called.
2. writeValue() - It would set the control value to the value with $ symbol, which I don't want. I want value without the $ symbol, on focus.

So, how can I call writeValue() before the focus event of the directive?

**Note**: Btw, 2-click functionality of cell-editor is working fine but I want 1-click solution, as I have set the focus on the control in `afterGuiAttached()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution by using `setTimeout`:

```js
 public afterGuiAttached(): void {
    // Set focus after the value has been written into the control
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    });
 }
```

Couldn't find any better solution. Let me know if you guys know or find any better solution. Thanks.